# Why is dignetur used as if it were in the active voice?

Tags: verbs, vulgata, passive-voice, deponent-verbs

For *2 Thessalonians 1:11*, the *Vulgata* has the following:

> In quo etiam oramus semper pro vobis: ut dignetur vos vocatione sua
>   Deus nosteret impleat omnem voluntatem bonitatis, et opus fidei in
>   virtute,

The verb *dignetur* is in the passive subjunctive, but it seems to be acting as if it were active. In the Greek, on the other hand, the verb, ἀξιώσῃ, is in the active subjunctive:

> εἰς ὃ καὶ προσευχόμεθα πάντοτε περὶ ὑμῶν, ἵνα ὑμᾶς ἀξιώσῃ τῆς κλήσεως
>   ὁ θεὸς ἡμῶν καὶ πληρώσῃ πᾶσαν εὐδοκίαν ἀγαθωσύνης καὶ ἔργον πίστεως ἐν
>   δυνάμει,

My question is: Since *digno* isn't a deponent verb, why does its passive form seem to be serving an active role?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

digno and the deponent dignor are both used in the same meaning "to deem worthy", but the latter is much more frequent. L/S have a separate entry for each of them.